# Deciding if block is movable in grid space

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a block that can be size 1x1, 2x2, or 3x3. It sits on a grid with different colored spaces. The only time a block can move between point (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) is if there are no spaces between the two points that have different colors. See the attached picture for an example showing when the block(s) can move.

[image]

My struggle stands that I cannot come up with a proper algorithm in my c++ code for finding out whether or not the block can move between two clicks points. Any suggestions for how this would work?

Another example from the Example Picture posted above, a 2x2 block cannot move down to (0,3) since there is a blue block in the way.

The blocks can be moved in horizontal, vertical, or diagonal directions. 
The blocks can be moved several spaces at a time, as long as they are not intersecting a different color that is in the way.

Comment: Can you include some code if possible?  I see an obvious brute force way of doing this, but perhaps that is not what you want.

Comment: I have no more code for this. I deleted it all in frustration. My initial loop for for all x between the two points and then for all y inside of the x loop. That was taking too long and very inefficient.

Comment: There are some lack of information here. Example: movements are restricted to horizontal and vertical only, or diagonal too? You move only by one block or several blocks each time?

Comment: Sorry, I have rushed to post. You can move diagonal or horizontal/vertical. The blocks can be moved several places at a time, but unless there is a different color blocking it

Comment: So, my question is, how do you deal with diagonal movement, in order to find a suitable path? By making small horizontal and vertical movements?

Comment: That is part of my struggle. I can't figure out when i can move the blocks in any direction, let alone the more complicated diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider only horizontal movements for while. So, suppose that you want your 2x2 block to move from (0, 0) to (3, 0). Note that you can imagine over your grid, a rectangle ([left, top] - [right, botton]) formed by convering a region from (0,0) - (4, 1). To see if it is possible to move, you only need to interate over this region to see if all colors are the same.

The same applies to vertical movement, using the same reasoning.

To accomplish diagonal movement, you can imagine it as being formed by small horizontal and vertical moves.

Comment: Is there a way to do this checking without a for loop inside of a for loop? Whenever I try to implement something like that it is really slow

Comment: If you know the size of your block, you can check all vertical grids while doing a for loop in horizontal movement. In a 2x2 block, there is only 2 check to be done on vertical grid for each horizontal one

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Lee's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm) could be useful here.

Imagine that you have a bucket of water at a node and you have knocked it over. A water stream starts to spread over all adjacent nodes and further and further (basically, it's a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)). There are could be walls and wells (nodes of different colors), which prevent water from spreading.

You can easily detect when your water stream reaches a goal node and you can reconstruct a route from it. If it's not possible, it will let you know about it.

At each node, you check adjacent nodes for colors and mark the current node as valid/invalid and visited.

The main problem is memory consumption. However, there are plenty optimized versions of Lee's algorithm, for example, consider [this link](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~haizhou/357/lec6.pdf).